# mysql - Combine 2 queries (insert and select) in 1 statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with i (primary),s and g columns. I have 2 queries:

```
INSERT INTO usertable (i, s, g) VALUES('1', '2', '5') ON DUPLICATE KEY SET s=(s*g+'2')/(g+'5'), g=g+'5';
```

and

```
SELECT s FROM usertable WHERE i='1' LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible to have both the queries in 1 query? Basically want to reduce number DB queries.

THanks

Comment: S means score of score table?

Comment: Yes, updated my question. Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to reduce the number of DB queries.  However, the two operations can be performed *atomically* if they are executed within the same transaction (and `usertable` is stored using a transactional engine such as InnoDB).

Comment: INSERT INTO usertable (i, s, g) VALUES('1',SELECT s FROM usertable WHERE i='1' LIMIT 1 , '5') ON DUPLICATE KEY SET (s*g+'2')=(g+'5'), g=g+'5';   try like that? I know I also confused what I m doing in query but try and share the result what this query will return

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing:  `(s*g+'2')`?  That doesn't look valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (IODKU) followed by a select, that is, 2 statements. Or you can wrap them in a stored procedure and make one. Perhaps not the answer you wanted to hear.

As for the IODKU, you naturally need a unique key to facilitate the clash that triggers the UPDATE section. That unique key can be one of the following:

- Primary Key (single column or composite)
- non-Primary key (single column or composite) with `unique` keyword

Note that an upsert clash can occur on more than one unique key. All it takes is one of the unique key clashes to trigger the UPDATE section.

A single call can be achieved with one to a stored procedure such as:

```
call myStoredProcName(param1,param2);
```

Further manual page references:

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
- [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) a.k.a. Composite Indexes
- [Working with Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) and [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: Yes, I think the stored procedure is the best way to go about. Thanks.